# codeigniter api for LOGIN and Signup

Tags: codeigniter

I have to make signup/login API using CI which is run in my localhost but when I run on server it shows the message page not found. Please see the attached screen.

```
This is my routes

$route['api/authentication/login'] = 'api/authentication/login';
$route['api/authentication/registration'] = 'api/authentication/registration';
$route['api/authentication/user/(:num)(\.)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(.*)'] = 'api/authentication/user/id/$1/format/$3$4';
```

I already changed my base URL. 
Please help....thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4A1z.png)

Comment: Can you add screenshot of live server postman request?

Comment: add...please see

Comment: I checked the shared url http://www.booknowservices.com/ but it is not accessible. There is something wrong with it.

Comment: http://booknowservices.com/  now check please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few other things you can do, other than changing your base_url

## **1. Set index page to empty string**

```
 //in your config.php file
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

## **2. Make sure that you have URI routing enabled in your htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
# use this if you have https server
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response sir...I change htaccess file but istill its not working...http://booknowservices.com/api/authentication/reigster

Comment: Already Do these changes...but still is not working http://www.jabraservice.com/api/authentication/login

Comment: Now It's working...problem is in my routes...and now it's solve....thank you, everyone, for guiding me.....Thanks a lot